# Filter Swagger Rest endpoint in Camel

Tags: apache-camel, swagger

I am using Camel 2.25, I am making an interface between several system.

I have some Http endpoint which will be call by  the different system. Now I can generate a swagger, the problem is it contains all the endpoints. I would like to generate swagger for each system which contains only the endpoint they will need.

I can achieve it by using .apiDocs(false) on all the endpoints for system1, then generate the swagger, remove this apiDocs(false) and add to the endpoint of system1 and generate swagger for system2

As you can see it is definitely not convenient.

Here is my restconfiguration:

```
restConfiguration().component("servlet")
        .apiContextListing(true)
        .apiContextPath("/api-doc")
        .apiProperty("api.title", "My Api")
        .apiProperty("api.version", "1.0.2")
        // and enable CORS
        .enableCORS(true)
        .apiProperty("cors", "true")
        .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);



        rest("system1")
                .consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
                .post("/example")
                .tag(system1)
               //


        rest("system2")
                .consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
                .post("/example2")
                .tag(system1)
               //
```

I am using camel-swagger-java for generating the swagger

Comment: Do you really have to expose services of all systems in a single REST API? Maybe you need an API Manager solution, then you'd expose a REST API for each system separately. Swagger will only keep a client-system from seeing the docs of other systems, not from calling services of each other. But if you must do that in a single Camel app, you could try initializing multiple Camel Contexts. Let me know if I misunderstood your issue.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, the point is to give the simplest Swagger to each system which will communicate with my interface, that why I dont want to poluate it with endpoint they don t need/ will not understand. 
From what I see multiple contexts is not recoomended (https://tomd.xyz/multiple-camel-contexts/)